# 404 Status Code Generated from Ashburn, Virginia to my public API Management on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

I'm working on a problem where I have a API Manager that is generating about 20k 404 Response Codes per day. I was looking at some post here on SO that lead me down the line of APIM Configuration but nothing applied to my situation.

I queried the Application Insights Log and began to see a common pattern.

All 404's in the last 24-hrs were generated from Ashburn, Virginia.

I also reversed the query to search for 404's that were not generated from Ashburn, Virginia for the last 24-hrs. My result was zero (0).

I had to go back to June 2, 2022 to find that only 27 404's were generated by clients other than Ashburn, Virgnia.

Does anyone have an idea what's happening in Ashburn, Virginia?

Another thing... Application Insights for APIM doesn't track the IP address of the caller. All IP Addresses are either 0.0.0.0 or blank. Other than using an authentication mechanism would it be possible to block these calls?

Thank your for help in advance.

Comment: Re: 0.0.0.0. You can disable masking IP addresses in Application Insights.

Comment: @ZakiMa - thank you for your response. I realized I was in the App Insights Analytics and not the logs. I am able to see the IP Address in the logs.